# QGIS - DXF export - setsymbologyexport

Tags: pyqgis

I have some Python script for exporting directly to a DXF file from QGIS, however with the update to QGIS version 3.34 some of my script has stopped working. (I was previously using 3.24)

I have been searching/trying alternatives but I can't seem to crack it.

Code:

```
dxfExport = QgsDxfExport()
dxfExport.setMapSettings(settings)
dxfExport.setDestinationCrs(settings.destinationCrs())
dxfExport.setExtent(canvas.extent())
dxfExport.setSymbologyScale(200)                    
dxfExport.setSymbologyExport(1)
```

In the notes for 'dxfExport.SetSymbologyExport' it references:
0 for NoSymbology, PerFeature and PerSymbolLayer as the values this can recieve.

Error:

> TypeError: QgsDxfExport.setSymbologyExport(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Comment: By the documentation https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#af4207af4a2b79dfeb89ce09684d1bc9e you do it right. But there is a note: "Prior to QGIS 3.32 this was available as QgsVectorFileWriter::SymbologyExport".

Comment: Yeah I did see that comment but I am unsure how to interpret it